# google pagerank api returns 403 at some urls

Tags: api, pagerank

Google API Call for the Pagerank of an url. in this example "spiegel.de" works:

http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr?client=navclient-auto&features=Rank&q=info%3Aspiegel.de&num=100&filter=0&ch=79909496714

Trying the same with another url "hotpress.com", all other parameters untouched, shows an 403 Error Page!

http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr?client=navclient-auto&features=Rank&q=info%3Ahotpress.com&num=100&filter=0&ch=79909496714

Why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the hash correctly, I use code from this place:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150223091918/http://99webtools.com/blog/php-script-to-get-pagerank

That I adapted a bit to get PR info for my search engine project. There's several other scripts also if you just Google it.

Answer (score 0):

Google is returning an error because the URL's `q` value is verified against the `ch` hash/checksum value.

You need to calculate the hash/checksum `ch` for each query `q`.

I don't know which hash algorithm is used here by Google, but "the Internet" thinks it could be [Jenkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function) or some version of it.

Comment: Plenty of folks for the past decade have been trying to hack that one, and a few have claimed to have done it, but never published their findings. The ones that did have some type of hosted solution are either no longer available, or just don't plain work.

Answer (score 0):

Now Google has stopped the Pagerank over this url `http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr` .... Find out some other way ..